# How to code a discord bot to delete messages that do not have a word in them

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Id like to code a bot for a vouch discord channel.

So of course I need to have people be able to give me a vouch and explain what it would be for.. but how would I code a bot that will automatically delete a message that doesn't start with the word "Vouch" or "vouch" (not case sensitive), but then doesn't delete the rest of the message because it contains something after the word?

If you can id also like a way to be able to exclude a certain role from that, so like with an owner role the bot does not filter me if possible, thanks for the help!

I tried this other code written by someone else but it deleted the messages if the message had anything else other than the word vouch in them.

So this is the code ive done so far, the bot is active and the code runs but it just doesnt monitor or delete any messages, please let me know what to change for it to work, ive turned on message content intent in the discord developer settings, and im sure my bot has the message managing role on both a discord role and the link that is created to add your bot, please help.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Project is running!")
})
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Dough Bot Here!");
})

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
})
const mySecret = process.env['token']

// Message create event listener
client.on('messageCreate', message => {

    // Checks if the message is in the vouch channel
    if(message.channel.id === 'vouch-channel'){

        // Converts message content to lowercase to make the check case insensitive
        content = message.content.toLowerCase()

        // Checks if the message starts with vouch
        if(content.startsWith('vouch')){
            return 
            // If the author has owner role, return
        } else {
            if(message.author.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Obese')) return;
            message.delete()
        }
            // Delete the message
    }

});

client.login(process.env.token)
```

Comment: "I tried this other code written by someone else but it deleted the messages if the message had anything else other than the word vouch in them" - have you tried to find out why that happens? Sounds like it should be easy to fix. Certainly easier than writing the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: I dont really know how im supposed to post the code i found, but i believe i may have found something that works but not with the role part, it still filters me and id like to post pictures in replies to the vouches that people give me

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the message is in the correct channel -> if it doesnt start with vouch -> if the message sender does not have role "Owner" -> Delete Message

Following is the code which does this:

```js
// Message create event listener
client.on('messageCreate', message => {

    // Checks if the message is in the vouch channel
    if(message.channel.id === 'Vouch channel id goes here'){
    
        // Converts message content to lowercase to make the check case insensitive
        content = message.content.toLowerCase()
    
        // Checks if the message doesn't start with vouch
        if(!content.startsWith('vouch')){
    
            // If the author has owner role, return
            if(message.author.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner')) return;
    
            // Delete the message
            message.delete();
    
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! so any message that is sent in the channel will be changed to lowercase, but this wont delete past messages will it? I dont want it to do that

Comment: Hi me again sorry, I tried the code but the bot doesn't work, I'm fairly sure everything works to the channels but anyone without my role can still say anything, is there a specific permission that the bot needs so that it can see message content as it's being sent? And do I need to have it on constant monitoring because I'm using upmonitoring and that's something about every 5 minutes :/. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey there, the bot needs the message content intent enabled, you have to enable it from discord developer portal, and add (assuming you're using djs v14) GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent to your intents. Looking at uptimemonitoring, as long as your bot is online, the code should work. (You also need message delete checked when you created invite link)

Comment: I added the Gateway intents bit and also enabled it in the discord developer portal, i checked and my bot definitely does have the "manage messages" checked when i created the invite link.. and yet the code still does not work.. (as in the code runs just fine but the bot does not do anything)